# Volume of a sound in ios

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

In my app I will to play a sound, so I looked on the web to found how to do this and I found that I should do the following operation:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@property(nonatomic,strong)AVAudioPlayer *player;

NSURL *musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sms_alert_circles" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];

[player setVolume:1.0];

[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

It works but the device reproduce the sound I wetted but with very low volume, so I changed this row: `[player setVolume:1.0];` to `[player setVolume:100.0];`, but nothing is happened.
So I tried to put on the headphones and I retry to play this sound and with headphones I hear the sound very well (a bit too much honestly). Why I hear the sound with very low volume by using the speaker of the iPhone? Why I hear the same sound with high volume by using the headphones? What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

have You tried this,

add MediaPlayer.framework to your project target

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0];
```

Thanks!

Comment: But to use this I should import something or it just work with the code I wrote? If I've to edit my code, can you post here a snippet in which you explain me what I should do? Thank you

Comment: You have to add MediaPlayer.framework to your target and import #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

Comment: I tried your solution: still the same, I can't hear the sound... How I can fix it? Have you understand that I will play a sound that I put in the bundle of my app?

Comment: Please refer this link, It'll help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164170/sound-of-app-running-on-iphone-too-low

Comment: It doesn't work... I tried to take a look the the page you suggested me: same problem... Plus the code you posted here it's old: it says that `[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0];` it's deprecated from iOS 7.0...

Answer (score 0):

The actual volume  lies between `0.0` to `1.0`.

Other than that, you probably will have to edit the file itself.

To ensure the with the system Volume

```
import #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
    [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0];//set system vol to max
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I still have the same problem: the audio is played with low volume if I hear it by using the iPhone speaker... Plus it says that `[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0];` is deprecated from iOS 7.0...

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that volume varies from `0.0 to 1.0 ONLY`.

and

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@property(nonatomic,strong)AVAudioPlayer *player;

NSURL *musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sms_alert_circles" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];

UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
        AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof (doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);

[player setVolume:1.0];

[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```